# Which network services depend on the "accept related input" iptables rule?

Tags: networking, iptables, webserver

**Background**

I am setting up a firewall for a webserver and was wondering if it would be a good security meassure to even reject RELATED input traffic and only except established connections by default.

**In practise**

For example using

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

instead of the common

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

since this should be more secure according to my understanding.

**Question**

Are there any problems with that? I know HTTP should be fine with it, and FTP which would have a problem could either have it's own rule with additional RELATED option, or (like in my case) might not be necessary at all.

But are there any other typical webserver services that might break because of that? Otherwise I like going with the more secure/narrower ruleset.

Answer (score 1):

> are there any other typical webserver services that might break because of that?

No.  As long as you correctly configure rules for FTP (if you plan to use it) you'll be fine with allowing ESTABLISHED instead of ESTABLISHED and RELATED

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! Do you also know if there would be problems with it as Samba Server (the various NETBIOS ports), or additional with LDAP (for ActiveDirectory access)? These are pertty much the only other services I could imagine acting up.

Comment: From my experiences, no, both will still work